# Replace an object item in object list with another item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io, lodash

I have an object of items in my variable `this.rows`. There is a real-time item coming from the server which is identical to one which is inside in `this.rows` object collection.

How to I replace an item with a new values ?

Here is an example:

```
    let rows = [
        {id: 11, active: 'no'},
        {id: 22, active: 'yes'},
        {id: 33, active: 'no'},
        {id: 44, active: 'no'}
    ]

    new_item = {id: 22, active:'yeah'};

    rows.forEach(item => {
        if (item.id === new_item.id) {
          return new_item;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you already check what google suggests you: replace item in array javascript? It has some answers. Hint: splice. Or simply even `rows.map(item => item.id === new_item.id ? new_item : item)`.

Comment: `findIndex` to find if the item exists in the array, then `splice` to make the magic happen

Comment: Or `find()` and `Object.assign()` to merge with existing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the "findIndex" method to look for  the index of the new item element in the rows array. Afterwards, check if a result was found (check if the index is greater than -1). Assign the item to the array using the position of the found element.

```
const indexOfItemInArray = rows.findIndex(q => q.id === new_item.id);

if (indexOfItemInArray > -1) {
   rows[indexOfItemInArray] = new_item;
}
```

Or use the "splice" method:

```
const indexOfItemInArray = rows.findIndex(q => q.id === new_item.id);
rows.splice(indexOfItemInArray, 1, new_item);
```

Comment: Your first option will work, but will fail to update Vue reactively (it's a Vue change detection issue), but splice will work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

To update easilly your array with a new value for specific id, use the `map` function :

```
rows = rows.map((row) => {
    if (row.id === new_item.id) {
        row = new_item;
    }

    return row;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

find item in rows and assign new item keys:

**mutate rows:**

```
_.chain(rows)
    .find({ id: new_item.id })
    .assign(new_item)
    .value();
```

**do not mutate rows:**

```
const newRows = _.chain(rows)
    .findIndex({ id: new_item.id })
    .thru(index => _.chain(rows)
        .cloneDeep()
        .set(index, new_item)
        .value()
    )
    .value();
```