# replace object in array base on index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

So, Im using react and I need to keep adding objects to an array of objects (object may have the same `index`, thats why I check for `label` and `index`). When the object that I want to add has the same `label` property as one that already is in that array, it should replace the previous object. So, lets say, only one object for each `label`. What I have works until I work with more then one `label`. When I do so, the array accepts more than one objects for each `label`...

```
 if (this.state.thumbnailsAtivas.some(thumbnail => {
     thumbnail.index === textura.index
 }) && this.state.thumbnailsAtivas.some(thumbnail => {
     thumbnail.label === textura.label
 })) {
     console.log("already in array");
 }
 else if (this.state.thumbnailsAtivas.some(thumbnail => thumbnail.label === textura.label)) {
     console.log("label already with item");
     this.state.thumbnailsAtivas.some((thumbnail, index) => {
         const tempData = (this.state.thumbnailsAtivas).slice(0);
         tempData[index] = textura;
         this.setState({thumbnailsAtivas: tempData})
     })
 } else {
     this.setState({thumbnailsAtivas: [...this.state.thumbnailsAtivas, textura]},);
 }
```

Comment: Are you able to link to full component code?

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin I dont have this online but I can pastbin this code. Hard to make it work outside my project, since Im getting dynamic data by axios

Comment: @NelsonSilva I forgot to mention `findIndex` earlier in the other question. Sorry!

Comment: so far its working, thanks again, you are a lifesaver :D

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace an object item in object list with another item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151692/replace-an-object-item-in-object-list-with-another-item)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another Array function called [**`findIndex`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which have the same usage as `some` but returns a result like `indexOf` does (returns the index of the element in an array or `-1` if no element matches):

```
let index = this.state.thumbnailsAtivas.findIndex(
    thumbnail => thumbnail.label === textura.label
);

if(index !== -1) {
    this.state.thumbnailsAtivas[index] = yourNewObject;
}
```

**Note:** To optimise your code a little bit, you could get rid of the call to `some` and use `findIndex` (once) for both checking existence and finding the index.